# Javascript not completing a loop

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, safari

My program should take the text from the first paragraph, duplicate it 100 times and put that into paragraph two. But when I do this function:

```
<html>
<body>

<p id="first">First</p>
<p id="second">Second</p>

<script>
var i;
var word = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML;
document.writeln(word); //Did this to check if it copied "first" correctly.
for (i=0; i<100; i++){
    word+=word;
    document.write(i) //Did this to see how man time it loops
}
document.getElementById("second").innerHTML = word;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

It returns this in Safari (Loops only 27 times):

```
First
Second
First 0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627
```

And Returns this in Chrome (Loops only 24 times):

```
First
Second
First 0123456789101112131415161718192021222324
```

Thanks!

Comment: Avoid `document.write()` function. It can be [idiosyncratic](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#document.write%28%29)

Comment: change to console.log to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your program is trying to do now to make the second paragraph contain 2^100 times "First", since you duplicate the duplicates, after the first loop you have 2*"First", then 4*"First" etc. This obviously gives memory problems. If you instead wanted to make the second paragraph contain only 100 times "First" you could just use:

```
<script>
document.getElementById("second").innerHTML = 
document.getElementById("first").innerHTML.repeat(100)
</script>
```

Comment: You are absolutely right! This is for a class assignment so we aren't allowed to use .repeat, but instead i corrected the for loop to not use duplicates. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

You mistake in that line . you add `word` instead of you have to add 'i'.
So it should be like this:

```
word+=i;
```